# Trying to understand hierarchical testing of nested regression models

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, sums-of-squares

I've learned multiple regression, but never did I learn hierarchical regression (i.e., the hierarchical testing of nested regression models) before.

[image]

Based on the image attached, I assume because the first F change is 2.783, the first F ratio is 2.783? How do we know if this first F ratio is significant?

Since the next F change is 2.775, does that mean the 2nd F ratio is 
2.783 + 2.775 = 5.558? How do we know if the 2nd F ratio 5.558 is significant or not?

I'm primarily interested in anxiety and avoidance measures, and their effect on Facebook use.